# Validation allow numbers only and phone number format on keypress using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Example:

See below image what exactly i need

[image]

Thanks anyone help this to simple code...

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: [Mask Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/)

Comment: @Satpal: Very nice plugin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've implemented below Masked Input Plugin to apply the same functionality what you need.

Step1 : Download this plugin

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin

Step2 :
Write Below code in your CSHTML or HTml Page.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ContactNo").mask("(+9) 999-999-9999");
        $("#txtContactNo2").mask("(+9) 999-999-9999");
     });

</script>
```

Hope this works  ! Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

```
link this script to your page and do masking format as you want

<script src="../JavaScript/jquerymaskedinput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

enter code here

and then write this inside script
$(function () {
        Masktext();
    });

function Masktext() {

        $('#<%=txtTelephone.ClientID %>').mask('(999)999-9999');   
        $('#<%=txtFaxNumber.ClientID %>').mask('(999)999-9999');    
        $('#<%=txtTelephoneMD.ClientID %>').mask('(999)999-9999');    
      $('#<%=txtTelephoneHC.ClientID %>').mask('(999)999-9999');    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event listener to the submit button (I am assuming that it has got an ID like `buttonId`), and check if the number is valid (I'm assuming that your number input has an ID like `numberId`), like this:

```
var button = document.getElementById("buttonId"),
    number = document.getElementById("numberId");

button.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (/[^0-9\-\+]/.test(number.value)) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("Please enter a valid telephone number!");
    }
});
```